# a weird string match issue using $ and grep

Tags: regex, grep

Got lost why add another , in the match pattern, it cannot match anything? What I want to achieve is to extract value for Foo in each record, i.e. 123, 234 and 345.

```
grep -o $"Foo*" grepdebugtest.txt
Foo
Foo
Foo

grep -o $"Foo*," grepdebugtest.txt

(match nothing)

cat grepdebugtest.txt
{"Foo":123,"Goo":456}{"Foo":234,"Goo":567}{"Foo":345,"Goo":678}
```

thanks in advance,
Lin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `*` operator in grep is different from the globbing operator used in the shell.

In grep `*` means zero or more repetitions of the previous character. Your pattern `Foo*,` matches `Foo,` `Foooooo,` and even `Fo,` but never `Foo":123,`.

To get the equivalent of the shell globbing operator you have to use `.*` in grep. Meaning zero or more repetitions of any character (`.` being the operator for any character)

Note, that taking this approach most probably you still don't match, what you are looking for, as grep will match greedy and take `{"Foo":123,"Goo":456}{"Foo":234,"Goo":567}{"Foo":345,` as match for `Foo.*`.

You might want to circumvent that problem matching with something like `Foo[^,]*,` instead.

Also note, that in case it isn't a typo anyways the `$` in the command line given is quite useless and the command the same as `grep -o "Foo*" grepdebugtest.txt`

Comment: Thanks mikyra, your solution works for me, and tried "Foo[^,]*" will output Foo":123
Foo":234 Foo":345, and how to control output only 123, 234, and 345 parts? Thanks.

Comment: Try piping output through `awk -F : '{print $2}'` - `grep -o "Foo[^]*," grepdebugtest.txt | awk -F : '{print $2}'` should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Use a JSON parser on JSON data:

```
jq '.Foo' <<END
{"Foo":123,"Goo":456}{"Foo":234,"Goo":567}{"Foo":345,"Goo":678}
END
```

```
123
234
345
```